# Naming convention rules does not seem to properly work when the default regular expression is overridden in SonarQube (Python)

Tags: python, sonarqube

Naming convention rules does not seem to properly work when the default regular expression is overridden (Python)

[image]

Comment: What did you override the regular expression to?

Comment: To the one that is displayed in the error message: ^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$

Comment: What language are we talking about?

Comment: Good question indeed :-) Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this problem. The only idea is that you have put by mistake a whitespace in the beginning of regular expression " ^[A-Z]...".

Comment: Thanks. It might be a could idea not to trim the whitespaces when displaying the regular expression on the rule page or in the error message.